# Is it possible to add optional binding parameters in a templatebinding?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'm busy creating templates for a medium-size project. I use knockoutjs with the jquery template engine and everything is going fine. I'm nesting some templates a couple of levels deep.
Now I would like to add optional binding parameters to some templates. This is my binding to the root template, inside a html table:

```
<tr data-bind="template: { name: 'RowTextboxTemplate', data: { caption: 'Transporter', property: Transporter } }" />
```

This is the rowtextboxtemplate template:

```
<td data-bind="template: { name: 'CellLabelTemplate', data: { caption: caption, property: property } }" />
<td data-bind="template: { name: 'TextboxTemplate', data: { field: property } }" />
```

And this is one of the subtemplates, the textboxtemplate:

```
<input data-bind="value: field, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" type="text">
```

Now, I would like to do this:

```
<tr data-bind="template: { name: 'RowTextboxTemplate', data: { caption: 'Transporter', property: Transporter, readOnly: IsTransporterReadOnly } }" />
```

However, I would like for it to be optional, so when omitting the last property it would still work. The reason I want this is that there are a lot of fields who don't require this parameter, so it would pollute my HTML.
I tried this in the root template:

```
    <td data-bind="template: { name: 'CellLabelTemplate', data: { caption: caption, property: property } }" />
{{if readOnly !== undefined}}
 <td data-bind="template: { name: 'CellComboboxTemplate', data: { options: property, selectedValue: selectedValue, optionsText: optionsText, readOnly: readOnly } }" />
{{else}}
 <td data-bind="template: { name: 'CellComboboxTemplate', data: { options: property, selectedValue: selectedValue, optionsText: optionsText, readOnly: false } }" />
{{/if}}
```

Next I bound the readonly property to the readonly attribute in the child template, but unfortunately this doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Might be nice to get a fiddle going.  One thing that you can do is use `$data.readOnly` in the binding, as it will not error out if `readOnly` is undefined because you are accessing it off of an object.

Comment: Thanks for the $data hint! that fixed the issue. I made a fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/ZRjWz/2/ reference it in your answer and I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that you can do is use `$data.readOnly` in the binding, as it will not error out if readOnly is undefined because you are accessing it off of an object.

This is described in a little bit more detail here: [knockout viewmodel property undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281196/knockout-viewmodel-property-undefined)

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRjWz/2/