# Knockout.js JSON data has optional attributes

Tags: json, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

The JSON returned from my server has optional attributes (e.g.) CompanyNumber is sometimes NULL and therefore it's removed from the JSON response for that specific company. (JMSSerializeBundle).

If I bind it to render all the companies in a table it crashes as soon as there's a company without a CompanyNumber. Is there way to prevent this from happening?

Current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(Routing.generate('contacts_companies_get_json'), function(data) {
    var companies = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings({
        'companies': companies
    });
 })
});
</script>

   <table class="table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Company Number</th>
           <th>Account</th>
           <th>Supplier</th>
           <th>Competitor</th>
           <th>Other</th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: companies">
       <tr>
           <td><a href="#" class="title"><span data-bind="text: name"></span> <span data-bind="text: legal_form"></span></a></td>
           <td><span data-bind="text: company_number"></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_account" ><i class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_supplier" ><i data-bind="if: type_supplier" class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_competitor" ><i data-bind="if: type_competitor" class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><span data-bind="if: type_other" ><i data-bind="if: type_other" class="icon-check"></i></span></td>
           <td><a class="btn btn-mini">Details</a><td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [knockout viewmodel property undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281196/knockout-viewmodel-property-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<div data-bind="text: name() ? name() : ''"></div>
```

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/fhVmPzRjdOs

Possible duplicate:  [knockout viewmodel property undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281196/knockout-viewmodel-property-undefined)

Comment: I'm getting this error Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: company_number is not defined;
Bindings value: text: company_number() ? company_number() : '' It works for the first one (which has a company number). The rendering stops when it hits the first company without a company number. (The company number is not defined in the JSON tree for that company when it's NULL)

Comment: I've added another link to a question that seems to be what you are looking for.