# knockoutjs mapping nested elements is not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping

basically looking mapping a json from ajax call.
my js

```
var mapping = {
    create: function(options) {
    return new Person(options.data.id,options.data.name,options.data.surname,options.data.address,options.data.amounts);
    },
    'address': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Address(options.data.id,options.data.street,options.data.number);
        }
    },
    'Amounts': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Amount(options.data.id,options.data.price,options.data.iva);
        }
    }    
};
```

I get an error : ReferenceError : fullAddress is not defined my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2coj72yn/1/
Thanks for hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, but it won't throw an error because the mapping plugin is used improperly.

### The problem of scope

First, `fullAddress` is a property of `Address` instances, so you should prefix it with `address.` Second, the `with` binding tells Knockout to look for `editingPerson.savePerson` which doesn't exist. So you have to change the binding to the root scope, like so: `click: $root.savePerson`.

```
<!-- current --> inputAddress: <input data-bind="value: fullAddress">
<!-- correct --> inputAddress: <input data-bind="value: address.fullAddress">

<!--current --> <button data-bind="click:savePerson" type="button">Save</button>
<!--correct --> <button data-bind="click:$root.savePerson" type="button">Save</button>
```

It is also advised to use objects as constructor parameter, allowing for easier use in combination with the `mapping plugin` and should you wish to leave out one property.

### The mapping plugin

The mapping plugin documentation clearly states that:

> All properties of an object are converted into **an observable**.

This means that you cannot include *computed* observables and expect them to just work. Indeed, the documentation has a part about augmenting JS objects with computed observables [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create). I might be wrong, but from my tests and the docs, it doesn't seem so that the `create` functions for mapping can be used for nested objects. Following this documentation, you don't need to create all observable properties explicitly, as a single call to `ko.mapping.fromJS` can instantiate them. Your new `Person` constructor would look like this:

```
function Person(options){
    // because these arrays contain nested objects with computed observables,
    // they should have a special create function
    var self = this, mapping = {
        'amounts': { create: function(options) { return new Amount(options.data); }},
        'address': { create: function(options) { return new Address(options.data); }}
    };  
    // instantiates all properties, eg. surname, name, id
    ko.mapping.fromJS(options, mapping, this);
    self.fullName   = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.name()+" - "+self.surname();
    });  
}
```

Another minor 'nit-pick': you can only use the mapping plugin's `create` functions on named object properties, so in your original fiddle, the plugin will never find the `persons` array because it is the data root.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/2coj72yn/3/) for the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $data prefix

```
<div data-bind="with:$data.editingPerson">
    id: <input data-bind="value:$data.id"> <br>      
    name: <input data-bind="value:$data.name"> <br>
    surname: <input data-bind="value:$data.surname"> <br>
    Full Name: <input data-bind="value:$data.fullName"> <br>
    Address: <input data-bind="value:$data.fullAddress"> <br>
   <table>...
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/baryon/NsuL7/1/

Source: [knockout viewmodel property undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281196/knockout-viewmodel-property-undefined)