# KnockoutJS: foreach binding array inside observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

This is my data model (a survey):

```
{ 
 "name" : "x",
 "questions" : [ .... ]
}
```

This is my viewModel:

```
survey : ko.observable(undefined)
```

This is my data-bind tag:

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: data.survey.questions">
```

It doesn't work. It works if I change the binding like this:

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: data.survey().questions">
```

The problem is that inside the foreach binding there's another foreach looping through the possible answers to the questions:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: answers">
```

I didn't find any way to make this one work with my current setup. Basically I think the problem is that you need to use an `observableArray` but I want to loop on an array inside an observable instead.

Can anyone suggest a way to make this double foreach work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout observables are functions. [To read the `observable`’s value, you need to call the observable with no parameters](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables). Hence you need the `survey()` to access the inner object which has `questions` property.

---

I'm not sure why your inner `foreach` binding isn't working. I would guess it's because you are setting `survey` to `undefined`. But since the outer `foreach` is working it couldn't be that. And you mentioned, *"I think the problem is that you need to use an observableArray"*. That's not necessary. Knockout's default binding handlers, including the `foreach` binding, internally handle this by using [`ko.utils.unwrapObservable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624401/when-to-use-ko-utils-unwrapobservable). The only difference being, if it's an `observableArray`, any changes to the array in the future will be reflected on the UI. But if it's a regular array, then the UI won't be updated.

So, if there is an array called `answers` within each `question`, then it should work. Here's a working snippet.

```js
var data = {
  survey: ko.observable({
    "name": "x",
    "questions": [{
      text: "Who let the dogs out?",
      answers: [
       {number: 1,text: "Cats"}, 
       {number: 2,text: "Baha Men"}
      ]
    }, {
      text: "What does the fox say?",
      answers: [
       {number: 1,text: "Woof Woof"}, 
       {number: 2,text: "Ring-ding-ding-dingeringeding"}, 
       {number: 3,text: "Meow Meow"}
      ]
    }]
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ol data-bind="foreach: survey().questions">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
    <br> Answers:

    <ul data-bind="foreach: answers">
      <li data-bind="text:text">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[Here's a fiddle for testing](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/oewydd14/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. My code is exactly like yours. The only difference is the  applyBinding. Since I'm working on a RIA and I switch dinamically the page content I use this snippet: ko.applyBindings({"data" : data}, $(".page-content")[0]); Also, the strange thing is that I get no error and this works flawlessly in the nested elements of the object (like the text question) but not on the nested foreach...

Comment: @Aurasphere that's strange. I have created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/oewydd14/4/) to mimic your structure. Make sure you have nested the array and the html properly.

Comment: I've solved the problem! It seems it was caused by a nested binding that was undefined preventing the parent to bind somehow... What I did to fix it was just adding a reference to the parent ($data) before the undefined binding. That let KO initialize the value itself, even if it's still not clear to me why I didn't get any error in console and why this isn't the default behaviour (I'm a JS newbie though). This was the answer that saved me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281765/4921205 I wouldn't be able to solve this issue without your help in debugging! Many thanks!