# knockout view model to represent a single object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Edit: This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735225/knockout-js-mapping-plugin-without-initial-data-empty-form) seems to have provided the solution; because I am a lazy sod and was trying to avoid having to define my model in two places (once on server, once on client) I figured there had to be a way. By using the custom binding in the linked solution, I'm able to have the observables created from the various form element data-bind attributes, so basically it builds the model from the form. So it's effectively driving the model definition from the form. I haven't decided yet if this is a bad idea :)

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong (or indeed, if I even *am* doing anything wrong). I need to create a form to edit a single record at a time, which has just got some simple text/number properties:

```
{ItemCode:ABCD,LotNumber:1234,ID:4885,MeasuredValue1:90}
```

I decided to use ko with the mapping plugin to do it. I'm fairly new to ko. 
Anyway I ended up with a view model like this:

```
var LotModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.Update = function(itemcode,lotnumber) {
    var data = { ItemCode: itemcode, LotNumber: lotnumber }
//DoAjax is just a utility function and is working fine.
        DoAjax("POST", "LotHistory.aspx/GetLotHistory", data,
        function(msg) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(msg.d, null, self);
            ko.applyBindings(self);
        },
        function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            AjaxFailure(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

And later on my code,

```
var lm = new LotModel();
```

and finally in $(document).ready

```
ko.applyBindings(lm);
```

Now it works, except that if you see in the view model, every time I load data I have to re-call **ko.applyBindings(self)** in the vm's Update function.
If I comment out that line, it doens't bind. I *think* that this is because I'm only binding a single object (i.e the view model itself is the object after the ko mapping plugin does its work) but everywhere I read about ko it seems to say "you only need to call this once, ever." 
So I can't help feeling I am missing something really obvious; commenting out ko.applyBindings(lm) in the document ready function doesn't make any difference because I automatically call lm.Update in document.ready but commenting it out in the viewmodel breaks it.

So my question is - am I doing this the wrong way? Is it overkill for just a single object at a time type binding? I mean it doesn't bother me too much, it works as I want it to but still, it's nagging at me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed best not to reapply bindings many times if avoidable. The problem is that you don't have any observable properties in your viewmodel to begin with. An initial call to `ko.mapping.fromJS` can fix this (or you can manually add the observables) e.g.:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({
    ItemCode: '', LotNumber: 0, ID: 0, MeasuredValue1: 0
  }, null, self);
```

See fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/qpwqH/1/

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Mentioning that the observables didn't exist gave me a big clue. Have found a possible solution here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735225/knockout-js-mapping-plugin-without-initial-data-empty-form].